# Starting Django virtual environment + build commands with gulp

Tags: python, node.js, django, gulp, python-venv

I am trying to make my Django project super portable and easy to start/stop. I'm using python's virutal environments along with a pip requirements file to manage python versions and pip packages. One concern I've always wondered about is migrating test data between databases. I'm utilizing:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > fixtures/data.json
```

to dump the current test data to a file and I want the next developer to pull this test data when they start their env using:

```
python manage.py loaddata fixtures/data.txt
```

So, the overall goal is to create a simple gulp command to do the following:

> pull latest git commit, start virtual env, merge test data into database, start server

I couldn't get gulp to start the virtual enviorment but if there is another way I should try and automate this, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`gulp-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) to run system command with gulp

install `gulp-shell` with npm:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp gulp shell
```

here is the sample **gulpfile.js** for your reference:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell');


gulp.task('default', shell.task([
    'git pull origin master',          // pull the latest data from remote repo
    'source $virtualenv/bin/activate; python manage.py dumpdata --database test > fixtures/data.json',   // activate the python virtual env, dump the data from test database
    'source $virtualenv/bin/activate; python manage.py loaddata fixtures/data.json'   // activate the python virtual env, load the data into production database
]));
```

Run gulp default task

```
$ gulp
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not starting the virtual environment. I am assuming it's because gulp is running the processes in another bash process and not the terminal I have open.

Comment: @SamMunroe yes, you are correct, i have updated my answer and run the `activate` command before the `python manage.py` command. and it should work now..

Comment: or maybe you can write your command in one shell script... that would be better than implement the distribution flow with gulp... as you know, gulp is used to handle javascript stuff...